# Trying to install Parallel IO on Unix, getting Error: Can't open included file 'mpif.h'

Tags: c++, bash, gcc, parallel-processing

http://www.cesm.ucar.edu/models/pio/install.html 
Instructions linked here

I am on item 3. and when I run gmake this is my output

```
>gmake[1]: *** [pio_kinds.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXXX/ParallelIO/PIO3/pio'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
[XXXX@YYYYY-login2 pio]$ gmake
Making dependencies for pio_kinds.F90 --> pio_kinds.d
Done updating dependencies
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/XXXXX/ParallelIO/PIO3/pio'
Making dependencies for pio_kinds.F90 --> pio_kinds.d
gfortran -c -DSPMD -DHAVE_MPI -DNO_MPIMOD -DNO_C_SIZEOF -DSYSLINUX -D_NETCDF -I/home/XXXX/netCDF//include -D_NOPNETCDF  -g -O2 -I/home/XXXX/netCDF//include    pio_kinds.F90
pio_kinds.F90:31: Error: Can't open included file 'mpif.h'
gmake[1]: *** [pio_kinds.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXXX/ParallelIO/PIO3/pio'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
[XXXX@YYYY-login2 pio]$ mpif90 --showme:compile
-bash: mpif90: command not found
>[XXXX@YYYY-login2 pio]$ module avail
```

I have tried loading different available modules,

compilers/gcc is loaded
mpi/openmpi iS loaded
following a search result i found on google, I unloaded compilers/gcc and and loaded mpich-x86_64 but that still gives the error.

Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: The last 3 lines 
XXXX@YYYY-login2 pio]$ mpif90 --showme:compile
-bash: mpif90: command not found
>[XXXX@YYYY-login2 pio]$ module avail

were just something I was trying from a search result, sorry do not concern yourselves with that please*

Comment: [solved] had two slashes in my environment where I directed the netcdf path
anyone with the same issue check your environment

Comment: A general wondering: How come on this Ux distribution, bash is not able to handle double slashes?

Comment: It seems to be able to outside of execution, configure, make, and make install. But when doing these, things the errors seem to be more fatal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install open-mpi. The error is similar to the one in [my question asked here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1214043/707756). Hopefully, the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1214062/707756) here would help you.